# Image does not "show up on canvas

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

I am trying to put a simple `png` to my canvas and download it, but the image doesn't show up. All I get is a white screen.
Maybe someone knows what I did not see.

```js
   

 // in my code i use FileSaver.saveAs(blob, name) but this is simpler
const saveAs = (blob, name) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = blob;
  a.download = name;
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}

const drawImages = (context, image) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      resolve('resolved');
    }
    img.src = image // = 'data:image/png;base64,...'
  } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
  }
})

const downloadCanvas = async() => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 8000;
  canvas.height = 8000;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  await drawImages(context, `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4         //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`);
  canvas.toBlob((blob) => saveAs(blob, 'name.png'));
}
downloadCanvas()
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: `All i get is a white screen` ... well, `document.createElement('canvas')` doesn't add the canvas element to the page - so that's why your page is blank I guess

Comment: You have more issues, like context.draw should likely be .drawImage. . Please create a [mcve] with all the bits like saveAs and an actual image like  `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
        //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: Your arrow function gives errors too: `new Promise((resolve, reject)) => `

Comment: `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';` new content is drawn behind the canvas content. `context.draw` you mean `context.drawImage`?

Comment: yeah i ment to use drawImage my bad. @mplungjan i also removed the extra `)`. Sorry i made a mistake there typing a minimal example

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add a `)` to your function. Please add the saveAs to the snippet

Comment: I do not see `a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Comment: Also I think you are missing `document.body.appendChild(a)` and the browser MAY not allow to click that without user action

Comment: thats why i added the comment that i in my programm use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Comment: So why change it here? it is easier to help if we know what you are using. For example https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/438

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. For everyone who is as confused as me later.

```
...
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = image // = 'data:image/png;base64,...'
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
...
```

This works with png/jpeg images.